# What is the difference between 'reprimand' and 'scold'?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

Can someone tell the difference between these?

Comment: what does the dictionary say?

Answer (score 2):

"Scold" is more specific in that it means to lecture someone or to verbally reprimand someone. "Reprimand" can mean to lecture or scold someone, but it can also mean another type of punishment. "Reprimand" however is especially used to mean a formal punishment, e.g. "The FBI reprimanded the agent who had been careless with classified information. As a result, his right to handle confidential information was revoked." "Scold," in contrast, suggests an informal punishment/lecture.